# How to get UserProfile to reference the fields from UserModel?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Just an fyi, I'm pretty new to programming & Django in general. I've been teaching myself.

Before I get into the problem, I'll share my Django code:

**models.py :**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    
    # DATABASE FIELDS
    email = models.EmailField(("email address"), unique=True)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    # META
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "User"
        verbose_name_plural = "Users"

    # TO STRING METHOD
    def __str__(self):
        return "User " + str(self.id) + " - " + self.email

class UserProfile(models.Model):

    # RELATIONSHIP
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        to = User,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE, 
        related_name = "user_account"
    )
    
    # DATABASE FIELDS
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="First Name")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Last Name")
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Profile Created On")
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="User Demographic")

    # META
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "User Profile"
        verbose_name_plural = "User Profiles"

    # TO STRING METHOD
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import User

class AbstractUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email')

class AbstractUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer, UserSerializer

from . import models

from .models import User, UserProfile

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'password')

class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'password')

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ("id", "user", "first_name", "last_name", "date_created", "role")
```

The `User(AbstractUser)` model comes with some default fields. Two of those default fields I'm trying to reference are :

> `first_name` & `last_name`

What I'm trying to do is, get those two default fields to connect with my `UserProfile` Model so that, when I create my User and fill out those fields, it will also show up in my `UserProfile` without having to fill it out there and connect it with a user.

Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this connection/reference of two models?

*(Just as an addition, I'm also using React for my frontend framework and have the requests working. It was just now that I realized I needed those two fields/models to connect after creating my SignUp component.)*

Comment: No need to do anything (except the answer by [@YoKe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66541338/14991864) you should be doing that). You can simply access the related model by the related field. So `user_profile.user.first_name` would give you the first_name.

Comment: Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat . I incorporated @YoKe 's answer however I'm getting this error back : `'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'first_name'` when I go to create my User Profile in the admin console. Any ideas on what could be going on?

Comment: You haven't run `python manage.py migrate` and `python manage.py makemigrations`?

Comment: No I have. I found the error, it was with my `def.string...` in my UserProfile Model. 

Now that I have everything working, the User Model still isn't connected to the UserProfile  Model in that, I still have to manually create it.

Comment: That is a different question...

Answer (score 0):

By default, `ForeignKey` refers to the primary key for relation. But we can also point to other fields using `to_field` parameter.

I haven't tried the below code yet. But you can do something like this in your `models.py`:

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    # RELATIONSHIP
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        to = User,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE, 
        related_name = "user_account"
    )
    
    # DATABASE FIELDS
    first_name = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field="firstname_field", verbose_name="First Name")
    last_name = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field="lastname_field", verbose_name="Last Name")
```

You can refer the document [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field).

Comment: I tried this method, but unfortunately it didn't work for me. I appreciate your help though!

Answer (score 0):

You need just to declare in `Userprofile` as `OnetoOneField` without declaring the `first_name` and `last_name` because User model has been declaring those field

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model()

    class UserProfile(models.model):
          
         user = models.OnetoOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```